Toilet tank filling slowly
I have replaced the fill valve and the flapper on my toilet. My toilet tank is filling very slowly. What else can I do?

it is not fully open, open by hand (push down) and see, then adjust

Adjust what?  You are not clear.

First, make sure the shutoff valve under the tank is fully open. If it is and it's still running slow, since you already replaced the fill valve, you may have an obstruction in the water supply line. Sometimes hard water will cause the washers in older, multi-turn shutoff valves to break apart and clog the line.
The easy way to tell is by closing the valve under the tank that supplies water to the tank. If the washer is bad the valve won't close completely and will continue to leak water into the tank. If that's the case, the shutoff valve needs to be replaced. It's not a particularly hard job but requires that you be handy with tools. If not, you may have to call a plumber.
